# What does the guy say after the girl said 알려줘

Tags: vocabulary

https://clyp.it/iga3axsf

What did the guy say after the girl said tell me

I think he's saying porn videos but I can't tell what sounds im hearing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A : 말해도 되나 ? Is is fine that I tell something ?

B : 아이 하지마 No. Do not tell.

C : 뭔데 알려줘 What ? Let me know

A : 야나두 공부하고 있거든 I study 야나두.

C : 아 진짜 Really ?

A : 미안해 미안해 얘기하면 안되는데 Sorry sorry. It is not fine that
I tell something (=I should not have taken your interest)

Comment: Lol he didn't say porn.  I googled 야나두 and it's some English teaching thing

Comment: I see. I edited.